# Git clone insteadOf

Tags: git

Does git clone not support insteadOf? I've tried git v1.8.3.1 and v2.16.5. My ~/.gitconfig contains

```
 [url "/home/USER/pub/"]
   insteadOf = GITPUB
```

The substitution works fine when adding remotes but not when cloning.

```
 git clone GITPUB/repo.git
```

fatal: repository 'GITPUB/repo.git' does not exist

```
 git remote add my_remote GITPUB/repo.git && git remote update
```

works fine

Comment: I just tried it and it seems yes — `git clone` doesn't rewrite URLs. Very strange. Thankfully, the workaround is very simple.

Comment: This seems... weird. Isn't this exactly what you are trying to do? https://www.oliverdavies.uk/articles/easier-git-repository-cloning-with-insteadof/

Comment: @NewEyes I saw the same article. Very strange that it supposedly worked for him.

Comment: @phd Is there any way to do this dynamically via some method other than `insteadOf`

Comment: The URL rewriting should work for prefixed URLs (`https://` and `file://` and so on). It fails with simple local paths because they bypass the URL code.

Comment: No, but as I said the workaround is simple. `git clone` is nothing more than `git init` + `git fetch` + `git checkout`. So run `git init <dir> && cd <dir> && git config url.<URL1>.insteadOf <URL2> && git fetch <URL2> && git checkout master`. Works for me.

Comment: @torek That should be the answer.

Comment: @phd I haven't tested it thoroughly yet though. :-)

Comment: AH HA! `git config --global url.file:///home/USER/pub/.insteadOf file:///GITPUB; git clone file:///GITPUB/repo.git` big thanks to @torek and @phd