# How to make git to redirect an url to a local path?

Tags: git, url

I have git url dependencies in my package.json and i would like to install them offline.

What i tried: 
My repository is in this folder: 
`file://c:/repository/folder/my-package/`

In my .gitconfig i added these lines

```
[url "file://c:/repository/folder"] 
insteadOf = git.remote.com/some/path
```

`npm i git+git.remote.com/some/path/my-package.git#v1.0.0`

I get this error: fatal:

`'c:/repository/folder/my-package.git'` does not appear to be a git repository

Comment: I'm nut sure I get your problem, but couldn't you just enter you local repository in your package.json?

Comment: Use [`git config [--global] url."https://".insteadOf file://`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+insteadOf). See the discussion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57509635/7976758).

Comment: I need the opposite. In my package.json for example have a package like this:  "package-name": "git+https://git.remote.com/some/path/repository-name.git#v1.2.0", And i would like to make git on npm install to not look for this repository pm the internet, but on my computer om a local folder where i would have the repositories

Comment: Then it's the other way round: `git config [--global] url.file://.insteadOf https://`

Comment: My repository is in this folder:  file://c:/repository/folder/my-package/

In my .gitconfig i added this
[url "file://c:/repository/folder"]
 insteadOf = https://git.remote.com/some/path

After this command: 
npm i git+https://git.remote.com/some/path/my-package.git#v1.0.0

I get this error:

 fatal: 'c:/repository/folder/my-package.git' does not appear to be a git repository